# Get profile picture other account on comment instagram graph-api | facebook defeloper

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-php-sdk, instagram-graph-api

Get profile picture other account on comment instagram graph-api |  facebook defeloper

```
$body = $fb->get('/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/media?fields=id,ig_id,username,media_type,comments{username,text,timestamp,user{profile_picture_url}},like_count,caption,children{media_url},comments_count,is_comment_enabled,media_url,owner{username,profile_picture_url},permalink,shortcode,thumbnail_url,timestamp', $page_token)->getBody();

$instagram = json_decode($body);
```

Cek this image to see result:

Image: [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXSZD.png)

Image: [View Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww6Q5.png)

---

[Facebbok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOYU3.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comment/#returnable-fields says,

> `user` (only returned if the user making the query also owns the comment, otherwise, the username field will be included)

So it looks like you simply *can’t* get the profile picture of other people who commented in this scenario. You will only get their name and their comment in that case, but you don’t get access to their profile picture URL.

Comment: oh iyaa coooy thx, in other case i try to get facebook name but i can't. whether this case is the same? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOYU3.png

Comment: no, to get facebook names, you must first have the permission "Business Asset User Profile Access" approved